# Call by reference in CSS?

Tags: html, css, reference

I explored in web and found a css code in this page:

**[CheckBox Custom Style](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/vLpwG)**

piece of code:

```
.input-helper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

But there's a `&` sign inside the code AND I have no idea what it is. I think it's like a "name holder", "name reference".
**Can someone describe what & means in CSS?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)/[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) variable that refers to `self`, in this case `.input-helper`

When compiled `&:before` becomes `.input-helper:before`

Comment: Actually, it is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).  Also, it isn't a variable.  It is what's called a *parent selector*.

Comment: is it valid in css2.1 ?

Comment: No, it is Sass.  You're supposed to compile it to CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon, how can you tell it's Sass? LESS syntax is the same.

Comment: @MichałRybak Look at the CSS window:  "CSS (SCSS)"

Answer (score 2):

It's like `.input-helper:before`, it's a Less/Sass variable

Answer (score 1):

If you've been using Sass for any length of time, then you're likely to be familiar with being able to reference parent selectors using the ampersand (&) character.

A simple Sass example looks like this:

```
h3
  font-size: 20px
  margin-bottom: 10px
  &.some-selector
    font-size: 24px
    margin-bottom: 20px
```

And here's how the output CSS looks.

```
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h3.some-selector {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

So, in your case, you will get this following code:

```
.input-helper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And

```
.input-helper:before{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

[See more information](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand)